# How can I use a for-loop to add matrices together for a CVXPY program constraint?

Tags: python, numpy, cvxpy

What should I do if I want to use a for-loop to describe one constraint for a CVXPY program?

For example,

```py
O=cp.Variable((n,n), symmetric=True)
```

and the constraint is $\sum_{i=0}^m A_iOA_i^*\succ 0$, where $A_i$ are of the type "np.matrix"? I use $B=\sum_i A_iOA_i^$, which is achieved by a for-loop,in which

```py
B+=A_i@O@A_i.transpose().conjugate()
```

and $B$ is of the type `np.matrix`, but it reported runtime error:

```
You're calling a NumPy function on a CVXPY expression. This is prone to causing errors or code that doesn't behave as expected. Consider using one of the functions documented here: https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html
```

I searched the error it reported and find this link: [cvxpy objective function error involving MulExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65517072). I think the reason should be this "non-cvxpy functions can't be used on cvxpy-objects". But I don't know how to achieve the for-loop to add the matrices together.

One demo:

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import math
m =10
init=np.zeros(shape=(16,16))
A=[]
O=cp.Variable((16,16), symmetric=True)
for i in range(m):
    A.append(init)
B=np.zeros(shape=(16,16))
for i in range(m):
    B+=A[i]@O@A[i]
```

Comment: If you're asked not to mix numpy and cvxpy operators, then just don't: ``B = sum(A[i]@O@A[i] for i in range(m))``